# Close Chrome Extension Sidepanel on URL Origin Change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a Chrome extension written in Manifest V3 that opens a sidepanel when the user clicks on the extension icon in their Chrome toolbar. I want the sidepanel to remain open on all tabs that have the same URL origin and automatically close when the user navigates to any other URLs. I tried to add an `onUpdate` event listener as explained in this code sample provided by Google: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.sidepanel-site-specific

However, after I open my extension on a tab, the sidepanel does not disappear when I switch to a tab with a different URL origin. I am running my extension locally with Chrome Version 115.0.5790.102

Here is my background.js file:

```
let activatedTabUrl = null;

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
  activatedTabUrl = new URL(tab.url).origin;

  await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
    path: 'sidepanel.html',
    enabled: true
  });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (!tab.url) return;
  const url = new URL(tab.url);
  if (url.origin === activatedTabUrl) {
    await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      path: 'sidepanel.html',
      enabled: true
    });
  } else {
    await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      enabled: false
    });
  }
});
```

My manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "my extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "desc",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Click to open panel"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", 
                    "storage",
                    "scripting", 
                    "tabs",
                    "sidePanel"]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To react to switching of tabs you also need to listen to chrome.tabs.onActivated.